# Qt 5.0.2 and Mingw 4.7 deploy

Tags: deployment, qt5

I search to deploy my application.
It is used Qt 5.0.2 and Mingw 4.7 as compiler.

I copied all the dll :

- D3DCompiler_43.dll
- icudt49.dll
- icuin49.dll
- icuuc49.dll
- libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll
- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- libGLESv2.dll
- Qt5Svg.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll
- Qt5Xml.dll

in my folder release.

All this dll are necessary, otherwise I get a message "... .dll manquante".

Now when I launch my exe in the release folder I get the message :

"Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Runtime Error!

Program: ...\release\test.exe

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."

Why this message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt5 on Windows requires qwindows.dll which should be deployed relative to the main executable like so:

- {yourAppPath}\YourApp.exe
- {yourAppPath}\platforms\qwindows.dll

EDIT {yourAppPath}\ is the plugin root directory and so \platforms\ and other plugins should be placed there, and not in {yourAppPath}\plugins as I had originally written.

Assuming that you are using Qt Creator and can launch your application at all try using MS's [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to discover what Qt DLLs are being loaded by your application.

Answer (score 0):

{qt path}/5.0/mingw491_32/bin have windeployqt.exe. This tool created to collect all relations automaticaly